# SQL Update Query: Counting records with current date

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a column named `ClientMigrated` of the format `7/23/2019 7:56:45 AM`

I have a query that is run within a macro to count the rows where the date portion of ClientMigrated is the current day.

```sql
UPDATE Tracking SET Tracking.UserMailboxesMigrated = 
DCount("ClientMigrated","[Mailbox Status]","ClientMigrated=Date()")
WHERE (((Tracking.ReportingDate)=Date()));
```

The query returns nothing because `ClientMigrated` contains the timestamp part which does not equate to the date.

I've tried to wrap `ClientMigrated` in a format function so that it compares to `Date()`:

```
format(ClientMigrated, "dd/mm/yyyy")=Date()
```

it seems is not acceptable syntax within `DCount`.

Suggestions to get around this is appreciated.

Comment: I see you've edited your question. Please post the error messages you are getting so we can help you.

Answer (score 1):

Consider [`DATEVALUE`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/datevalue-function-03878f08-b0db-42df-8a0c-279939637c6f) to extract the date portion of a date/time field:

```
UPDATE Tracking t
SET t.UserMailboxesMigrated = DCount("ClientMigrated", 
                                     "[Mailbox Status]", 
                                     "DATEVALUE(NZ(ClientMigrated, ""1900-01-01"")) = Date()")
WHERE (DATEVALUE(t.ReportingDate) = Date());
```

Comment: Sadly, that syntax produces an "! Unknown" dialog.   It seems DCount does not like functions within its parameters.

Comment: Hmmmm...works great on my end! How are you using this SQL? Are you saving it in a stored query or building it in code? If latter, you need to double up the double quotes to be VBA syntax compliant. But it is better to save as a stored query. Then run the action with `DoCmd.OpenQuery`.

Comment: The syntax is correct, so that error is caused by something else. Could be _Null_ values in one of the date fields.

Comment: It is in a stored query.

Per above, this is what I have:


UPDATE Tracking AS t SET t.UserMailboxesMigrated = DCount("ClientMigrated","[Mailbox Status]","DATEVALUE(ClientMigrated)= Date()")
WHERE (DATEVALUE(t.ReportingDate)=Date());

Running the query results in "! Unknown".

Comment: Are you using the MS Access.EXE GUI? Or as ODBC connection to an .mdb/.accdb file? I checked with ODBC and OLEDB from Python (not VBA) with *still* no issues using `DCount` and/or `DATEVALUE`. Please describe your environment, even Access/Window versions. Where do you see `! Unknown`?

Comment: I'm using ACCESS 2016 (GUI) on Win 10 ver 1607.  The table in question is native access, not an ODBC connection.

Comment: Ah! I did reproduce. @Gustav is correct. It has to do with missing, `NULL` values in column. See edit using `NZ`.

Comment: OK.   Not clear on the resolution.   All of the rows in my [Mailbox Status] table have NULL values in the ClientMigrated column except for those where a date/time was populated.    What is corrective action?

Comment: Did you run the edited version above? What resulted?

Comment: @Parfait You'll need to escape the double-quotes surrounding the `nz` default date.

Answer (score 1):

*Nz* should return a date value, not a string, for *Null*:

```
UPDATE Tracking t
SET t.UserMailboxesMigrated = DCount("ClientMigrated", 
                                     "[Mailbox Status]", 
                                     "DateValue(Nz(ClientMigrated, #00:00:00#)) = Date()")
WHERE DateValue(t.ReportingDate) = Date();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to utilize the [`FORMAT`](https://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/date/format.php) function

Assuming that you are using the default value for `DATE()`, you should be able to use:

```
UPDATE Tracking
    SET Tracking.UserMailboxesMigrated =
            DCount("ClientMigrated", "[Mailbox Status]", "ClientMigrated=Date()")
WHERE (((Format(Tracking.ReportingDate, "dd/mm/yyyy"))=Date()));
```

Comment: This may not work as applying `FORMAT` renders a string type not comparable to date type. Plus, day-first is a regional setting. Check with `Debug.Print Format(CDate("7/24/2019 7:56:45 AM"), "MM/DD/YYYY") = Date()` which returns `False`.

Comment: The formatting needs to be applied to "ClientMigrated" within the DCount, not the WHERE clause.

Comment: Jerry, @Parfait is right. It's the timepart that is the issue. Converting to text will positively fail.

Answer (score 0):

To use an index on`ClientMigrated`you should check the datetime field for being same or greater than today (`Date()`) and smaller than tomorrow (`DateAdd(""d"", 1, Date()`). The`""`escapes the double-quote for the`DateAdd`interval-parameter nested in the`DCount`criteria string.

```sql
UPDATE Tracking
SET UserMailboxesMigrated = DCount("ClientMigrated", 
                                     "[Mailbox Status]", 
                                     "ClientMigrated >= Date() AND ClientMigrated < DateAdd(""d"", 1, Date())
WHERE ReportingDate = Date();
```

`ReportingDate`is a date not a datetime? If datetime, use same pattern, but you must not escape`DateAdd`double-quotes.